# Why does SE retain the copyright for user-submitted blog posts and comments?

Tags: discussion, blog, copyright, licensing

The footer of the main SE sites contains the following statement:

> site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

In contrast, the community blogs for SE sites have this footer:

> Stack Exchange © 2014 Entries (RSS) and Comments (RSS). CC-Wiki

Why are the copyright and license statements different in the first place? I would have expected the blog posts to be treated exactly as posts on the main site. Why does SE explicitly declare their copyright for blog entries when they intentionally don't to it this way on the main site and rely on everything being Creative Commons?

Comment: Doesn't  "Entries (RSS) and Comments (RSS). CC-Wiki" mean that "Entries (RSS) and Comments (RSS)." are CC-Wiki?

Comment: @RichardTingle there is a period between entries and comments and cc wiki, there isn't a period between we copyright and entries and comments. On looking closer, this just looks hopelessly ambiguous to me, which is something a copyright footer should not be.